# Offline Redis 7 install

Tags: offline, redis

I am trying to install Redis 7 on Ubuntu 20.04 with a no internet connection, but I am not able to find the .deb file.
Is there any repo where I can download it?

Comment: It isn't a `.deb` file, but the Redis website [provides a download you could use](https://redis.io/download/). If you want Redis as a `.deb`, you can get it [from the Ubuntu package repo website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/redis). But the one for Focal (20.04) doesn't appear to be version 7, so you may need to download that from their website

Comment: thanks @cocomac. I ended up compiling and building myself the .deb file. Thanks to jedi4ever for inspiration: https://gist.github.com/jedi4ever/944216/01402396251dab271d52035d02a66da4e15a75a7